# Why is different spacing displaying between different div classes with the same margin settings?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am creating a FAQ page here: http://staging.nwcm.com/2017/07/06/faq-custom-css/

Here is my css:

```
/*TAB SETUP FORMATTING*/

div.tab_counter_0, div.tab_counter_0 active_tab, div#tab-id-1-container {
border-color: #339966 !important;
}

div.tab_counter_1, div.tab_counter_1 active_tab, div#tab-id-2-container {
border-color: #009999 !important;
}

div.tab_counter_2, div.tab_counter_2 active_tab, div#tab-id-3-container {
border-color: #3399ff !important;
}

.tab {
font-size: 1.5em !important;
}

/*END TAB SETUP FORMATTING*/

div.ufaq-faq-category h4 {
font-size: 1.5em !important;
margin: -5px !important;
}

div.ufaq-faq-category-inner {
margin-top: 1.5em;
margin-bottom: -1em;
}

div.ufaq-faq-body {
margin-top: -18px !important;
}

.ufaq-faq-post p, .ufaq-faq-post li {
font-weight: 800 !important;
clear: left;
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ufaq-faq-title, .ufaq-faq-category-title {
margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

**WEBSITE INFORMATION** (not sure if this is important): I am using the Ultimate FAQ (1) plugin on a Wordpress site with the Enfold theme (2) with the Avia Layout Builder, both by Kriesi.  The tabs are built-in inside my theme, the content inside of the tabs are all my individual categories of FAQ Questions.  Here is the shortcode for the content of the first tab:

```
[ultimate-faqs include_category='your-contributions']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='employer-contributions']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='roth']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='eligibility']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='vesting']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='401k-distributions']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='rollovers']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='loans']
```

**THE PROBLEM**: The spacing between different div classes, with the same styling, results in variable spacing between these elements.  I need the space after each title, before each answer, to be consistent.  It appears that this difference happens when the question is longer than one line.  To get a good picture of the issue, please see:

Your Contributions:

- Must my employer offer a 401(k) plan?
- I changed jobs this year.  What if I contributed...?
- How much can I contribute?

Vesting:

- If I after I leave the employment of a company...?

---

**LINKS**:

(1) https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-faqs/

(2) http://www.kriesi.at/themes/enfold-2017/

Comment: Sugestion: Margim bottom is applied "after" element. If you have two lines with same paragraphy is applied only 1 time. What you need is change line-height property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this issue because of the '+' and '-' minus symbols. They are assigned a `height` and the space between the question and answer is because of this `height`. It's a bit complicated to explain. I will post a solution. See if it works for you.

```
.ewd-ufaq-post-margin-symbol{height:21px;}
.ufaq-faq-title-text{margin-bottom:10px;}
```

Add this at the bottom of the FAQ plugin's CSS file or better yet hunt down the styles responsible and change them. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd love to understand why that works if you have time to explain.  Either way - you're a life saver, it worked!

Comment: If you inspect, you will find that `.ewd-ufaq-post-margin-symbol` had a height of 35px, when all it needed was 21px. This extra 14px had been pushing the answer below it, downwards. When any question took up two lines, however, the 14px wasn't enough to push the answer down as the question exceeded the extra 14px and the answer butted up against your question. So, the first style rule to fix the extra height and the second style rule to make the spacing consistent for all questions and answers. Hope that made sense.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you